# Two request instead of one in Ajax call in Phoenix app

Tags: ajax, phoenix-framework

I'm getting two different requests with just one call (one click on the HTML element) and that is generating an error on the second request, as you can see here:

```
[info] PUT /editables/Pag6
[debug] Processing by Skeleton.EditableController.update/2
  Parameters: %{"editable" => %{"content" => "<p>Oá</p>"}, "par" => "Pag6"}
  Pipelines: [:browser, :browser_session]
[debug] SELECT e0."id", e0."title", e0."content", e0."inserted_at", e0."updated_at" FROM "editables" AS e0 WHERE (e0."title" = $1) ["Pag6"] OK query=154.2ms queue=15.2ms
[debug] BEGIN [] OK query=0.4ms
[debug] UPDATE "editables" SET "content" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "id" = $3 ["<p>Oá</p>", {{2015, 9, 17}, {23, 15, 17, 0}}, 9] OK query=7.5ms
[debug] COMMIT [] OK query=7.4ms
[info] Sent 302 in 309ms
[info] PUT /editables/9
[debug] Processing by Skeleton.EditableController.update/2
  Parameters: %{"editable" => %{"content" => "<p>Oá</p>"}, "par" => "9"}
  Pipelines: [:browser, :browser_session]
[debug] SELECT e0."id", e0."title", e0."content", e0."inserted_at", e0."updated_at" FROM "editables" AS e0 WHERE (e0."title" = $1) ["9"] OK query=0.7ms
[info] Sent 404 in 42ms
[error] #PID<0.301.0> running Skeleton.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: PUT /editables/9
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Ecto.NoResultsError) expected at least one result but got none in query:

from e in Skeleton.Editable,
  where: e.title == ^"9"
```

The first request is Ok, and "par" parameter has the correct "Pag6" value but in the second request "par" has a wrong (it recalls me an id) "9" value.
The Ajax is:

```
$("#save").click(function() {
  var content = $("#editor").html();  
  $.ajax({
    url: "/editables/Pag6",     //URL do controlador para a função que quero usar, neste caso PUT para fazer Update (4 é a ID da row)
    type: "put",
    data: {
      editable: { content: content,
//                  title: "pageN"
      }
    },
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf 
    },
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function () {
      alert( "Data Loaded");
    }
  });
});
```

I can't understand why these are happening:
1) two request instead of just one;
2) the wrong "par" parameter value in the second request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the origin of the second Ajax request, keep a XHR breakpoint in Chrome devtools for "Any XHR".

When an XHR is triggered, the execution will be paused. You can go back in the stack trace to find which code actually triggered the request.
[image]